# vertx Java download filename special characters

Tags: java, encoding, vert.x, download

I am writing a simple file download by Java and vertx and I can't get correct filenames, for ex:  gadže zèleno_iscusinţă.pdf (This is romanian language)

Here is my code:

```
ctx.response()
        .putHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, contenype)
        .putHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format(inline; filename="gadže zèleno_iscusinţă.pdf")
        .putHeader(HttpHeaders.TRANSFER_ENCODING, "chunked")
        .sendFile(filePath).end();
```

With this code makes the download file name have the wrong format:

```
gad-e zèleno_iscusin--.pdf
```

I've tried to use URLEncoder.encode(), to end code the filename:

```
.putHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format(inline; filename=URLEncoder.encode("gadže zèleno_iscusinţă.pdf"))
```

But it makes all space into "+" which is not good :(. gadže+zèleno_iscusinţă.pdf

Does anyone know any method to make this name in the correct format? Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it.... Use UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1. The code will something like this.

```
String fileName = "gadže zèleno_iscusinţă.pdf";

String encodeFileName = new String(fileName.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");

ctx.response()
        .putHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, contenype)
        .putHeader("Content-Disposition", encodeFileName)
        .putHeader(HttpHeaders.TRANSFER_ENCODING, "chunked")
        .sendFile(filePath).end();
```